# SQL/parameters: positional and (then) named?

Tags: sql, oracle, parameter-passing, named-parameters

While calling a procedure/function in Oracle, is there a rule for the sequence of parameters of positional and named (and default) types?
...like the positional params come first...
...or the named appear at the last of the list?
Any examples (it is not in documentation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using a version of Oracle that supports mixing named and positional parameters (if memory serves, that was new in 11g but I wouldn't guarantee that), the positional parameters need to come first.  Logically, if you're trying to use positional parameters, the positions would need to be correct.

And this is certainly documented.  Check out the [Positional, Named, and Mixed Notation for Actual Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825) section of the PL/SQL User's Guide

Comment: @popstack - Confirm what?  As I indicated, the ability to use mixed naming is new in 11g.  And the documentation I linked to is from 11.2.